# Pandas: how to apply custom function to split free text column into structured data?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a free text column in a *DataFrame*, for which I have developed custom handler:

```
a, b, c, d, e, f = my_transform(text_column)
```

How do I apply it to DataFrame in order to create 6 new columns *a, b, c, d, e, f* containing results of transformation?

Answer (score 2):

Without your function it is a bit problematic, but works if return `Series`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text_column':['abgdeftk', 'ewerfsfs']})
print (df)
  text_column
0    abgdeftk
1    ewerfsfs

def my_transform(x):
    #some sample fransformation 
    a = x[0]
    b = x[1]
    c = x[2]
    d = x[3]
    e = x[4]
    f = x[5]

    return pd.Series([a,b,c,d,e,f])

print (df.text_column.apply(my_transform))
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  a  b  g  d  e  f
1  e  w  e  r  f  s
```

Comment: Cool, will give it a try!